# Combining two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: `Team` and `player`. Team player id's table. When I run the tool url, url and name of the player Starring table, I want to take.

player table

player

```
p_id  p_name            p_url
1   Iker Casillas   iker-casillas
2   Mesut Ozil      mesut-ozil
3   Xavi            xavi
4   Victor Valdés   victor-valdes
```

team

```
t_id   t_name           t_url      player

1      FC Barcelona     fc-barcelona     3,4
2      Real Madrid C.F. real-madrid-cf   1,2
```

team url is running, players want to print the name and url.but I can not get the result. where I make mistakes.

```
include('confing.php');

$t_url = $_GET["t_url"];
$sql = mysql_query("select player.p_name,player.p_url from player,team where player.t_id = team.t_name and team.t_url='.$t_url.'");

while($write = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo '<a href="'.$write['t_url'].'">'.$write['t_name'].'</a>';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're trying to say here. Could you rephrase your first paragraph?

Comment: What kind of error message do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    team a
        INNER JOIN player b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.p_ID, a.player) <> 0
WHERE   a.t_url = 'valueHere'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33167/2)

one more thing, your code is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please read the article below to prevent from it

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: "FIND_IN_SET" the first data printing. "CONCAT" and prints a list of all the players. How do I print all of the team players only.

Comment: can you explain more about what you said?i can't understand it.